# Bounty box overflows "add comment"

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

[image]

The "add comment" becomes hardly visible. I think it should be shifted down just a bit...

I'm using Chrome version 35.0.1916.153 m

Comment: Same thing happening to me too (using 35.0.1916.153).

Comment: @Bakuriu yes totally

Comment: Same thing in Firefox 29.0.1. I wonder why `.question-status` has `margin-bottom: -5px;`.

Comment: *"The "add comment" becomes hardly visible."* Subtle hints in the UI...

Comment: @Cody Gray: Eeeek! Comments are about to be abolished from Stack Overflow!

Comment: Similar 'issue': the box that shows the number of upvotes jon skeet has received in the C# tag, it goes out of bounds

Comment: Exact duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/233821/179541. There was even a bounty (which I've finally gave to the only answer before giving up this issue). Originally I've posted it on SO meta, but I've noticed that it happens on many sites, so I "moved" it to SE meta. 69 people seen my question whilst this one 255, at this time. Unfair. Just unfair :)

Comment: Same problem on Internet Explorer 11 on Windows 8.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build, which should be in the next 8 hours.

Comment: Yep, it seems it has been fixed.

Answer (score 12):

Quickfix - inside the bounty box:

```css
.question-status {
    margin-top: 15px;
/**/margin-bottom: -20px;
    width: 657px;
    background-color: #EEE;
    line-height: 150%;
/**/padding: 8px 8px 15px 60px;
    clear: both;
}
```

Quickfix - outside the bounty box:

```css
.question-status {
    margin-top: 15px;
/**/margin-bottom: 15px;
    width: 657px;
    background-color: #EEE;
    line-height: 150%;
    padding: 8px 8px 1px 60px;
    clear: both;
}
```