# Editing a Post to Format a Table

Tags: discussion

**Is it right to edit a post to format a table, for example?**

From this

```
Col1    Col2       Col3
1       607989      A
2       607989      B
3       607989      C
4       607989      D
5       607989      E
6       607989      F
```

to this?

```
╔══════╦════════╦══════╗
║ Col1 ║  Col2  ║ Col3 ║
╠══════╬════════╬══════╣
║  1   ║ 607989 ║  A   ║
║  2   ║ 607989 ║  B   ║
║  3   ║ 607989 ║  C   ║
║  4   ║ 607989 ║  D   ║
║  5   ║ 607989 ║  E   ║
║  6   ║ 607989 ║  F   ║
╚══════╩════════╩══════╝
```

My editions this type are always very controversial, with some people saying it is too minor to be a valid edition and a lot of other people approving it? In general they are approved.

**What do you think about?**

*My opinion is that makes the post more readable and then the edition is good for the community.*

---

**UPDATE**

I think a more relevant question appeared here:

Supposing this is not the only edition, is it good to format tables (or make other editions without this one would be preferable?)

Comment: This breaks copy paste.  I don't think it adds much either.

Comment: [These edits](http://stackoverflow.com/users/358614/nizam?tab=activity) of tables are wrong. The OP [clearly stated what output they want](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/25277117/revisions), how do you know that they want pipes in their output? Edits should not change the original meaning/requirement of the question.

Comment: Also, as most of the edits are related to SQL outputs, it's practical to get what the OPs have mentioned. Drawing pipes in output tables is an unwanted additional requirement to the question.

Comment: That's why I am asking this here. Because they were controversial but most of them were approved. Then I thought it would be good to have a discussion about this here. This is not a consensus (you can see it by checking some editions I have made). Anyway, I wont't do it anymore.

Comment: Do you think I have been downvoted because the question is silly or because the people don't agree with the formatting? Since my editions are being approved, it doesn't seem the question is not good (which means this needs to be discussed)

Comment: Following up on what @JohnPalmer said: If there's any chance someone might want to copy and paste the output and parse it with an awk or Python one-liner or the Excel text import thingy or whatever to help debug the question, the lines are making things worse. If not, then it's just a style issue and I don't really care.

Comment: @Nizam You can't really judge if they're accepted by the community based on approval rate, due to robo-reviewers, which makes it very smart for you to have asked about it here. Go with the consensus on this post for this edit.

Answer (score 7):

I don’t think it’s particularly useful. First, I find the former perfectly easy to read, but then if I were to defer to what I take as a relative authority on the subject, [the documentation for the `booktabs` LaTeX package](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/booktabs/booktabs.pdf) has this to say:

> ### The layout of formal tables
>
> You will not go far wrong if you remember two simple guidelines at all times:
>
> 1. Never, ever use vertical rules.
> 2. Never use double rules.

Oops! This violates both. If you look at the examples in that document, it might be justifiable to format it like this:

```
-----------------------
Col1    Col2       Col3
-----------------------
1       607989      A
2       607989      B
3       607989      C
4       607989      D
5       607989      E
6       607989      F
-----------------------
```

But frankly, I don’t see a whole lot of improvement from either of these changes.  Since I find it perfectly readable as is, I would leave it alone and would probably reject any suggested edit which changed only that.

Comment: You have a very good point and you are in a good companion. I think it solves the question. I will just wait till tomorrow to see if another one says something different, since my editions this type are usually approved. Depending of what the majority say here, I won't edit tables anymore.

Comment: Sorry for asking this as comment, but the upvotes and downvotes in meta stackoverflow are considered to reputation? Thanks.

Comment: @Nizam No, they don't participate in the visible rep. They may result in question bans though, not sure.

Comment: Anyway, @icktοοfay, how much authority does that document have? Rule 2 sounds like a matter of personal taste, and rule 1, well, I can think of many situations where vertical lines between columns can help clear the layout up.

Comment: @MrLister According to Brad Larson, [question bans are not enabled on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266742/100-days-later-was-the-split-a-good-idea#comment67860_266816).

Comment: @MrLister: I’m not sure it has a whole lot of authority. I primarily object not on the basis of some document on the Internet, but mostly because of the perceived lack of value on my part of the change. It is merely augmented as an additional opinion by that document (with perhaps a *little* more weight; they do seem to know what they’re talking about), whose advice I have followed in the past.

Comment: This is old now, and if you use vertical rules appropriately Stack Overflow will actually provide nice table formatting.