# Rejection Reason - Unnecessary Formatting

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, specific-edit

I know this question comes and goes in different variations over the years, but we still see lots of edits that format tables, or format code but often the format didn't actually improve the post.

I propose that **Unnecessary Formatting** is added as as a Rejection reason on edits

> This type of edit risks introducing errors into the edited content that are hard to identify. The visual improvement needs to outweigh the potential risk, if there is not significant improvement to the readability of the post you should avoid this type of change.

### From the consistent confusion for reviewers and the editors alike, the rejection guidance needs to be changed

The documentation for posters is I think OK, when OP formats tables and code, it is generally good enough, however editors get overzealous in the area of table and code formatting where these are the only changes.

Personally, if the edit didn't improve the readability, I'm inclined to reject the edit for these reasons:

1. Formatting a table or code can easily introduce errors if you are not paying attention, these errors are just as hard for a reviewer to spot if we are not going to compare every single cell value. These errors may not matter to the post, but in some cases could be detrimental as tables or code are often used to display expected or actual behaviour, an errant cut and paste issue could vastly alter the conversation for OP

   - I don't have an example buy many of us should have seen alteast once, where a post looks like OP duplicated the expected and result tables, meaning we can no longer see the issues, on closer inspection an edit to format the tables copied the same table twice, losing OPs actual data.

     > This *should* have been **clearly conflicts with author's intent** or **causes harm** but it's easy for the reviewers to miss the finer details where single cell values or the order of records might be out.
   - A similar issue is common with code edits, editor might change the formatting of some variables, but not all, or they anonymize some fields inconsistently making the code no longer compile, which leads to comments hating on OP because their code snippets don't even compile.
2. Formatting that goes over the top in terms of cell lines then it gets hard to copy the table into code so we can reproduce or test to assist OP, this answer is a good summary on this particular issue: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/268595/1690217
3. I would prefer that the editor spent their time fixing things that actually need to be fixed and kept the review queues clear.

If we had a standard rejection reason **Unnecessary Formatting** then this would remove ambiguity on rejection notices, but also make it clear to Reviewers that this is an appropriate reason to reject

- As a reviewer, the guidance is not clear on *is this acceptable* (edit that formats tables)

  - I want to respond with *no improvement whatsoever* but i feel like that is still not appropriate, the edit might be a visual improvement to some users, but it comes at great risk or effort that the improvement does not justify. That why's I would prefer to have an **unneccessary formatting** rejection notice or something of that nature, the editor clearly felt like this was a worthy improvement.

Before posting here these were the previous discussions that still left me confused as to the proper response:

- [Editing a Post to Format a Table](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/268594/1690217)
- [The latest on creating tables using markdown for SO post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/371772/1690217)

I just feel like lately my review queue is full of these table edits and I'm getting lazier in the effort I put into making sure they are correct, when most of the time I wonder why the editor bothered to do it at all in the first place.

Review in question: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/27116579
[image: Review in question]

Comment: those type of edits are made by a single user. It is much easier and effective to reach out to them and ask them to stop then have the system adapted and all reviewers trained to click the right button.

Comment: @rene these edits was made by me. I paid attention to all the indicated shortcomings and I will not proposal them in the future.

Comment: thanks for being a good sport @timnavigate don't be discouraged, we need good editors and even if you're only working on badges there are heaps of articles out there that need your help.

Comment: @timnavigate just to clarify: I appreciate that you try to help with edits making questions better. The lack of (markdown) table support on Stack Overflow is obvious at the moment so getting a table with data right is a hassle, specially for new users. When I stumbled on your edit I checked whether the revision you edited was indeed a failed attempt at producing a table. It wasn't in that case nor was it in the case presented here. Then it becomes a matter of style/preference. I would love to approve your edits if you actually add a table where one is needed but not properly provided.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This example seems to be truly "no improvement whatsoever."  It does not make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, more accurate or more accessible, which is exactly the description of that rejection reason.

As far as accidentally introducing errors, the diff doesn't make that particularly difficult to check.

Overall, I think this proposed change risks confusing reviewers and causing people to reject edits that *do* meaningfully improve formatting.  We *should* be approving those, with the necessary care to ensure that errors aren't being introduced.  For those that don't improve anything, there's "no improvement whatsoever," and if it does a bunch of disruptive things while making a tiny improvement, then you can write that in the custom rejection reason (which can also handle other disruptive changes, like grammar edits that risk confusing the meaning of the post).

Comment: I think the crux of the issue is that it is an opinion-based edit; it clearly makes the post easier to read/more accurate *for the people/person making the edit*, otherwise they probably wouldn't be making it... it's just that a lot of *other* people don't find the edits to be an improvement.