# What metrics can we use to identify tags most in need of clean-up?

Tags: discussion, tags, low-quality-posts

For my sins, I spend a fair amount of time hovering around the [excel-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-vba) tag and, in my experience, almost all the questions there are [unclear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25337773/data-set-method-date-is-not-filling-in-the-column), [poorly researched](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24832516/is-it-possible-to-write-a-vba-code-that-removes-duplicates-from-only-cells-that) or ["do my job for me"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21351428/exporting-excel-data-based-on-variable-columns) questions.

I enjoy doing a bit of clean-up now and again, and VBA is one of my strong suits so I tend to hang around there to help out. But it would be good to know which other tags are in need of clean-up operations to see if any might suit my expertise.

For reference, here are the [top 20 most down-voted tags](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/220388/worst-behaving-tags). ([excel-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-vba) is not in the list!)

And here's how to find [the worst offenders by tag](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/220389/worst-question-with-tag-x?Tag=excel-vba).

Can you think of any other good way to use the SQL API to identify tags in need of clean-up?

Comment: Argh! Not a popular question. Anyone want to say why? (Downvoters?)

Comment: Perhaps people think discussing what tags are the worst is not too constructive?

Comment: Hmm... Fair point @3to5businessdays. I'll consider deleting. Don't want to encourage negativity. Just thought it might be a fun discussion.

Comment: By the way, I'm not unaware of the delicious irony of having a down-voted question which I myself tagged with [tag:low-quality-posts]. Ha ha!

Comment: Yeah, I think the down votes exist because it's difficult to see how this discussion could yield useful actions on anyone's part.

Comment: For the people closing this as "opinion based", please read [this comment](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266742/100-days-later-was-the-split-a-good-idea#comment68143_266742) by Tim Post♦

Comment: I voted to close as "opinion based", in lieu of a "not constructive" close reason. (We used to have one, but it is now MIA. Very important on a Meta site, I think.) It serves little point to lambast the quality of questions in particular tags. We all have an opinion about that, and we might even come to a consensus, but it doesn't do any good to sit around navel-gazing. **If you have an actual proposal to *do something about this problem*, feel free to suggest it.** A discussion about that might be productive. I'd vote to re-open in a heartbeat. I agree this is a problem for many tags.

Comment: I've majorly reworked the question to make it more constructive, less negative, and less opinion-based.

Answer (score 4):

Unanswered % is a good rough estimate of tag quality. A lot of unanswered questions in a tag is a sign that there are a lot of bad questions being asked.  If a tag consists of more than 25% unanswered questions, there's a good chance that it could use a little bit of clean up. Some tags are over 40% unanswered and could use a lot of attention.

Jon Seigel wrote a SEDE query a while back that finds the most [Unanswered Questions by Tag](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/42823/unanswered-questions-by-tag). Those tags that score the highest could use a few folks filtering on them in the [close votes /review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/5628603). The [newest tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-vba?sort=newest&pageSize=50) for a tag is another good place to look for questions that can be added to the /review queue by voting to close. (Of course you can also *answer* questions from that tab to boost the answered % up a little bit.)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is a useful approach trying to separate good tags and bad tags. I do believe some tags can attract better questions than others, but all widely used tags have good and bad examples of questions and answers.

And if good examples exist, this is the approach I believe it would be more useful to focus on.

Regarding [excel-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-vba), which I frequent (more asking than answering) I believe some low quality content is related to the fact Excel is a popular program and while many users can handle formulas and other GUI-supported actions, they are not that familiar with macros.

Even when the question is not that good, it is common to have a useful answer attached to such questions.